# Regex match string in url

Tags: regex

```
http://example.com/ru/regiony/
http://example.com/regiuni/
https://example.com/obshestvo/regiony-zastavili-ego-zhiti
http://example.com/obshestvo/regiony
```

I need check, if in url I have link: `http://example.com/regiony/` or `http://example.com/regioni/` or `http://example.com/regiony` or `http://example.com/regioni`

My regex:

```
(regiony\/?|regiuni\/?)
```

But this is not working. I match all

Comment: Probably `^http:\/\/[^\/]*\/region[yi]\/?$`

Comment: not working this

Comment: Is it in some GA filter? Try `^region[yi]\/?$`

Comment: `regiony` `regiuni` in links

Comment: Are you parsing HTML? What is the programming language?

Comment: php language... $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']

Comment: how do you process the regex? i think it maches all because you dont use the subpattern

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
\/regi(?:uni|ony)(?=$|\/)
```

- http://example.com/ru**/regiony**/
- http://example.com**/regiuni**/
- https://example.com/obshestvo/regiony-zastavili-ego-zhiti
- http://example.com/obshestvo**/regiony**

  1. `\/regi(?:uni|ony)` matches /regiony or /regiuni
  2. `(?=$|\/)` end of string/line or `/` must follow (positive lookahead)

Alternatively use

```
\/regi(?:uni|ony)(?:$|\/)
```

to include the trailing slash (**/regiuni/**)

Answer (score 0):

If you are only interested in finding the segment `after http://example.com/`, then you can use this:

```
(region[iy][-/]?)|(regiuni[/]?)
```

This should cover all (six) possibilities: *regioni, regiony, regioni/, regiony/, regiuni, regiuni/*. Added *regiony-, regioni-*.

Comment: Not. https://example.com/obshestvo/regiony-zastavili-ego-zhiti this links matches. But I don't need this.

Comment: Just added a '-' to the first option.

Answer (score 0):

For your example data you might use a pattern like:

[`^http://.*/regi(?:on[iy]|uni)/?$`](https://regex101.com/r/PxBfNk/1)

Or with the example url in the match:

[`^http?://example\.com.*/regi(?:on[iy]|uni)/?$`](https://regex101.com/r/PxBfNk/2)

This will use `$` to assert that this pattern `regi(?:on[iy]|uni)/?` occurs at the end of the line. You could use another delimiter for `/` like `~` so you don't have to escape the forward slashes.

For example:

```
$pattern = '~^http://.*/regi(?:on[iy]|uni)/?$~';
$string = "http://example.com/ru/regiony/";
if (preg_match($pattern, $string)) {
    echo "Valid: $string" . PHP_EOL;
}
```

[Test Php](https://3v4l.org/NTAO8)